# SSH not working on OpenElec Frodo

Tags: ssh, openelec

I am using Rasperry Pi Model B.  I installed Frodo (12.2) on it and everything works fine.  I can ping the box, use browser interface etc..

I am facing issue with SSH.
I did following things:

1. Kept ssh in cmdline (it was there in image and didn't remove it)
2. Created files 'ssh_enable' but no luck. (so created some other files like 'enable_ssh' 'ssh_enabled')

I don't see any issue with network.  I can ssh to other PC of network.

I also tried checking TCP port of SSH (22), but it says connection refused.

```
telnet 192.168.0.89 22
Trying 192.168.0.89...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.89: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for me (I use the RaspberryPi headless, i.e. without monitor/television connected, was to:

1. turn the RaspberryPi off,
2. take the SDcard and put it into my card reader at my PC.
3. There I mounted the first partition on the SDcard and changed the file `cmdline.txt` in the root directory (aka `/` directory), adding the word `ssh` to the line that ended with `quiet`

There are many other interesting boot arguments (unrelated to ssh) described [here](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/Boot_Arguments).

More ideas in [this OpenElec forum thread](https://forum.openelec.tv/showthread.php?tid=76256).

Answer (score 1):

Openelec Settings

Services

Enable SSH

this worked perfectly for me, I then logged in using SSH from my HTC1 phone using root as the pi user didn't work

Comment: This only works if you have a monitor/screen/television connected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little bit here and I can try to help you. Are you trying to SSH into Raspberry Pi running openELEc from a Windows?

On [OpenELEC SSH](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/ssh-into-raspberry-pi-for-remote-administration/) can be enabled during installation. To connect to it, you can use PuTTY from Windows. Again you may already know this but your question was not very clear to me.

Comment: No.  Tried from MAC and Ubuntu.

Comment: This »answer« should be a comment to the question. This is not an awful forum — fortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using current stable version 3.2.4 from http://openelec.tv/get-openelec/download/viewcategory/10-raspberry-pi-builds ?

According to [OpenELEC website](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/OpenELEC_FAQ#I_run_OpenELEC_3.0.6.2C_and_ssh_doesn.27t_work_anymore._Why.3F),

> SSH is now disabled by default. This is due to security reasons. We
>   disabled it by default as ssh normally would not be needed. With
>   OpenELEC 3.1.x and higher, this has been implemented in the
>   OE-settings add-on.

Try enabling ssh from OpenELEC configs from `XBMC>Add-ons>OpenELEC_config` (alternative locations: `XBMC>Programs>OpenELEC` or `XBMC>Settings>OPENELEC`).

Also, make sure ssh service is ON under `XBMC>System>Services`, if that option is available for OpenELEC.

New versions of OpenELEC may not recognise `ssh_enable` file.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#enabling-the-server):

> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named `ssh`, without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD Card. When the Raspberry Pi boots, it looks for the `ssh` file. If it is found, SSH is enabled and the file is deleted. The content of the file does not matter; it could contain text, or nothing at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add **ssh** as the kernel parameter. There should be a txt file in the boot partition of the card for that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPi.SE you could further improve your answer by being more specific (e.g. provide the name of that file or how that parameter string looks like).